# PHP Fatal Error: Call to undefined method

Tags: magento2, shipping, fatal-error

I have installed this brazilian shipping module -
 https://bitbucket.org/igor_lm/igorludgero_correiosofflinem2 - then I got the error:

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Igorludgero\Correios\Model\ResourceModel\Cotacoes::getCollection() in /magento221/vendor/igorludgero/correios/Helper/Data.php:276
  Stack trace:
  #0 /magento221/vendor/igorludgero/correios/Cron/UpdateTracks.php(24): Igorludgero\Correios\Helper\Data->updateOfflineTracks()
  #1 [internal function]: Igorludgero\Correios\Cron\UpdateTracks->execute(Object(Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule))
  #2 /magento221/app/code/Magento/Cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(292): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
  #3 /magento221/app/code/Magento/Cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(228): Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver->_runJob(1511677080, 1511677144, Array, Object(Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule), 'igorludgero_cor...')
  #4 /magento221/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/Invoker/Invoker in /magento221/vendor/igorludgero/correios/Helper/Data.php on line 276
```

This does not seem to be a coding issue since it works for others, I also had opportunity to talk with its autor. So I was wondering it could be related to php config. I found out similar php fatal errors on google regarding **short_open_tag** set to off but that was not the case. It doesn't look like **max_execution_time** problem either.

Does anyone know which configuration could possibly cause such call to undefined method?

```
Magento 2.2.1
PHP 7.0.25
MySQL 5.6.33
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have download the module and find out that `getCollection` method is not exists in the `Igorludgero\Correios\Model\ResourceModel\Cotacoes` class. Seem like a bug in the module. Usually `getCollection` method used in the regular models, not in the resource model. Try to contact the author of this module, or fix it by yourself - change this method:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
                            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
                            \Igorludgero\Correios\Model\ResourceModel\CotacoesFactory $cotacoesFactory)
{
    $this->_storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_cotacoesFactory = $cotacoesFactory;
}
```

to this one:

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
                            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
                            \Igorludgero\Correios\Model\CotacoesFactory $cotacoesFactory)
{
    $this->_storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_cotacoesFactory = $cotacoesFactory;
}
```

I think this should work, because we just changed the resource model factory to the simple model factory. In the all places this factory is used as a regular model factory.

This changes exists since the [77473019194767fd482c8b8d47874a12596a234e](https://bitbucket.org/igor_lm/igorludgero_correiosofflinem2/commits/77473019194767fd482c8b8d47874a12596a234e) commit, when the regular model was changed to the resource model factory, and I dont imagine how it can work for the other users without errors after this "update".